# Using strtok in while loop; warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses

Tags: while-loop, warnings, strtok

As part of a much larger program I am using strtok in a while loop.

while(cmd2Args[count] = strtok(NULL, " ")){count++;}

But the following warning is received 
warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses
      [-Wparentheses]

The program successfully compiles and functions as intended. 
Under what situations should such a warning be considered?
Is this bad programming style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is bad programming style. If the code is written exactly in the way you wanted it, then you may disregard the warning, but it may not be so.

In C, an assignment is an expression. That means that the code `x = 4;` not only assigns a value of 4 to `x`, it IS a value of 4 on its own. So you may write `y = (x = 4);` and your `y` will have a value of 4.

That being told, the `while` clause must have a value in the parentheses.

```
while(value) { /* loop body */ }
```

Very often, you need to compare two values in there, like `while(x == 42) { /* do stuff */ }`. But what happens if you forget to put a second '=' and write `while(x = 42) { /* do stuff */ }`?

Well, instead of comparison, you have an assignment. But here's the trick. They are both **values** (expressions, to be correct). And while `x == 42` has a value of zero when `x` is different from `42`, `x = 42` will always have a value of `42` and will pass the condition test.

That is why modern compilers put a warning if they see an **assignment** inside `while`, `if`, and so on. If the code is correct and you really want to have the assignment there, put an extra set of parentheses around it.

```c
while( (cmd2Args[count] = strtok(NULL, " ")) ) {count++}
```

That is getting us back to the compiler warning message: If you want to use the result of an assignment as a condition, put parentheses around it.

Other way of writing it would be

```c
while( (cmd2Args[count] = strtok(NULL, " ")) != 0 ) {count++}
```

where the programmer's intention is made clear.